# game fails to run when exported from unity to android 'Unfortunately game has stopped'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity.I created a level in unity and when I am trying to export it to android mobile device or emulator,I am getting a message "unfortunately,the game has stopped" and closes.Can anyone please specify the reason for this....Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide more information, and show us some code if this is possible. Right now it is difficult to tell what is the cause of the problem. Is there some exception thrown ? Edit your question useful information!  Here are some hint http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you have the android sdk tools installed you should be able to run "adb logcat" which should give you more detailed information about what's failing. Most likely it is an exception (null reference exception is very common).  When you run in the editor you are probably getting the same error, but it isn't fatal in the editor.